# In a custom framework, should Triggers be allowed to retrigger by default?

Tags: apex, trigger, design-patterns, framework

I am developing a Trigger framework for our org and I’m faced with a decision of whether to automatically disable a Trigger once triggered or to keep enabled. I’ve got enableTrigger() and disableTrigger() methods but I’m curious what others think the ideal “default” state should be for all code in the Handler class.

As of now, I’ve got “enabled” as the default and the dev would have to explicitly disable it (then re-enable). I like this because the assumption of enabled seems more intuitive, but disabled seems more useful as a default.

Comment: Of course you would want it enabled by default. You want your triggers to run the first time, right?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sorry, should clarify. The framework would allow the first set of context variables through the trigger logic but prevent any DML on records of the same object made during that transaction from re-triggering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should **almost always** execute your triggers as many times as they occur. There's a precious few reasons why you would want to avoid running triggers more than once, and it's almost always possible to avoid disabling triggers by using intelligent updates (e.g. only updating records that actually need to be updated).

Simply disabling after first use has two issues. First, in your Apex Code, you can operate on more than 200 records, but disabling the trigger after first use means that all records past 200 won't be processed. Second, disabling the trigger means that workflow field updates won't re-trigger records, which may also cause issues. The only way to be safe is to leave it enabled as default.

In practice, blocking triggers should only occur in two situations: (a) recursion calls are too complicated to solve any other way, and (b) during unit tests. The reason why you want to disable triggers during testing is so that you can mock up your initial data without consuming all your governor limits. You should still enable them for the main tests to make sure you don't exceed governor limits.

By the way, if your intent is to block recursion using this mechanism, re-enable the triggers at the end:

```
trigger ... on ... (...) {
  if(TriggerUtil.isDisabled('XYZ')) {
    return;
  }
  TriggerUtil.disable('XYZ');
  // Do stuff here
  TriggerUtil.enable('XYZ');
}
```

This makes sure that updates of more than 200 records work correctly, while still preventing recursive loops when you have something like Contact Update -> Account Update -> Opportunity Update -> Contact Update. Of course, this also takes some care to make sure that all relevant data is updated.

You might also intentionally disable triggers from other triggers during recursion to avoid recursion. For example, if the Account trigger needs to update Contacts, have it disable the contact trigger ahead of time, then re-enable it when you're done. This allows the trigger to work during direct updates, but is disabled for the Account trigger.

```
trigger ... on ... (...) {
  ...
  TriggerUtil.disable('XYZ');
  update xyzRecords;
  TriggerUtil.enable('XYZ');
}
```

So, basically speaking, you need to consider what you're disabling, and use appropriate techniques to make sure that business logic is enforced, while still staying within the governor limits. I've presented at least two different techniques you can use, and you'll find others when you think about them. However, no matter what you do, disabling recursive updates should be a **last resort**, not a *default*.

Note: Obviously use a handler class, the above code is only meant to be illustrative.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I was controlling for the > 200 issue by grabbing all Trigger context variables in an object first, then disabling, then passing the object into handler methods. In thinking more about it, I do agree that blocking re-triggering should be a last resort. I actually ended up writing a DML helper method which takes a string param of the class name with the disable/enable method...it disables the specified trigger, performs DML, then re-enables it. Mostly I was annoyed by taking 3 lines of code to disable-DML-enable.